# wraping global functions in (function($){ }(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was writing a global javascript function. And after some mistakes (and a few searches here) I got it to work. But I also saw an example with (function($){  `code here`  }(jQuery);

what is the difference (if any) and is there any advantage between option 1 and 2? both perform my task well. I am just trying to learn the difference.

**OPTION #1**

```
(function($){

     TEAM={
        getQB: function( success, failure) {
             var user=USER.user_data.login.toUpperCase();
             $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/nfl/getQB?username="+user,
             dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: success,
            error: failure,
             timeout: 6000
              });

           },
         getRB: function( success, failure )
            {
                 userx=USER.user_data.login.toUpperCase();
                   $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/nfl/getRB?username="+userx,
             dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: success,
            error: failure,
            timeout: 6000
                    });

            }
     }

})(jQuery);
```

**OPTION #2**

```
    var TEAM={
        getQB: function( success, failure) {
             var user=USER.user_data.login.toUpperCase();
             $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/nfl/getQB?username="+user,
             dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: success,
            error: failure,
             timeout: 6000
              });

           },
         getRB: function( success, failure )
            {
                 userx=USER.user_data.login.toUpperCase();
                   $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/nfl/getRB?username="+userx,
             dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: success,
            error: failure,
            timeout: 6000
                    });

            }
     }
```

Comment: If that's all the code, there's no difference, except that option #1 will fail in strict mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript immediately invoked function patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984652/javascript-immediately-invoked-function-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

`(function($){ code here })(jQuery)` is an immediately-invoked function expression. It provides a temporary scope for variables declared within it. So in this instance, you're passing in a reference to `JQuery` that will be accessed by `$` just within that block of code.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); //Remove assignment to $

(function($){
  console.log($); //jQuery function 
})(jQuery)

console.log($); //undefined
console.log(jQuery); //jQuery function
```

**Option 2**

If your code isn't within a function scope, it attaches `TEAM` to the `window` object. This pollutes the global namespace and couple potentially cause problems down the road. Imagine if someone made another object/function with the same name in the global. Depending on your code, your `TEAM` can be overwritten.

**Option 1 is then preferred so you can avoid namespace collisions.**

Comment: Note: to get `jQuery` to give up being assigned to `$` you have to call `jQuery.noConflict()`. Otherwise exactly correct!

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I forgot that the assignment was automatic.

Comment: awesome thanks a million! Now i see why other people did option 1.

Answer (score 0):

In the first option you are sure that you use jQuery, because you are passing it as a parameter of the closure. In the second option you may have something else which stands behind *$*.