# this reference is not working in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see `this` works in below code only in `init` function and functions called within init (e.g.: `onSearchClick`). Can anyone explain why `this` is not working in `onSearchClick`? And what this pattern is called as?

```
(function() {
    var e,
    Search = {
        ele: {
            sb : $('.searchSubmit'),
            st : $('.searchText')
        },
        vars: {
            debug: true
        },
        init : function() {
            e = this.ele;
            this.addEvents();
        },
        addEvents : function() {
            this.ele.sb.bind('click', this.onSearchClick);
            //Search.ele.sb.bind('click', this.onSearchClick);
            //Both, this. and Search. work
        },
        onSearchClick : function() {
            Search.log('onSearchClick:  - ');
            //this.log('onSearchClick:  - ');
            //Only Search. works, this. not
        },
        log : function(p_sMessage) {
            if(!Search.vars.debug) { return; }
            else { if(window.console) { console.log(p_sMessage); }}
        }
    };
    window.Search = Search;
    window.e = e;
}());
Search.init();
```

Comment: FYI, there is is no need to use an IIFE if you are making the only two variables inside of it global anyway.

Comment: *"And what is this pattern of JavaScript called?"* The design pattern is often called an IIFE, or Immediately Invoked Function Expression, though there are other names for it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984652/javascript-immediately-invoked-function-patterns

Comment: Hi @FelixKling , thanks for you response. I will add all elements of DOM in `ele` variable further.

Comment: You can bind `this` context with `this.ele.sb.bind('click', this.onSearchClick.bind(this));`

Comment: `this` is special in JS, and has various uses.  From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this :"When a function is used as an event handler, its `this` is set to the element the event fired from ...".  This behaviour is overriding how you are trying to use `this` and therefore creates an issue.

Comment: Hi @VickyGonsalves thanks for reply. It executes once on init now, not on click later :(

Comment: Thanks @Paul ! You got my problem exactly. Here `this` is the button by which this function is executing. I will have to define `this` in a var. Can you please give me a hint on which level, I should put it?